# Java HTTP POST and GET converted from CURL

Tags: java, curl, httpclient, http-get, cookiestore

Hey all I am trying my best to convert this working CURL script to Java:

```
@ECHO off
set COOKIES=.\cookies.txt
set USER=myUN
set PASSWORD="myPW"
set HOST=https://zzzzzzz.zzzzz.zz.zz:9443

cls

ECHO "Get the session cookie-------------------------------------"
    set out1 = curl -k -c %cookies% "%host%/qm/authenticated/identity" > nul
ECHO "-----------------------------------------------------------"

ECHO "Use the session cookie to logon----------------------------"
    curl -k -L -b %COOKIES% -c %COOKIES% -d j_username=%USER% -d j_password=%PASSWORD% %host%/qm/authenticated/j_security_check > nul
ECHO "-----------------------------------------------------------"

ECHO "Use the cookie to get the catalog--------------------------"
    curl -k -L -b %COOKIES% -H "Accept: application/xml" %host%/qm/process/project-areas/_zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz/members
ECHO "-----------------------------------------------------------"
```

where:

```
               -k: Allow insecure server connections when using SSL
    -c <filename>: Write cookies to <filename> after operation
               -L: Follow redirects
        -b <data>: Send cookies from string/file
-H <header/@file>: Pass custom header(s) to server
        -d <data>: HTTP POST data
```

I've searched around for java code that includes an example of creating a cookie but I have yet to find something that would help me with my code above.

The closest I could find and modify the **POST** call is this:

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
String USER     = "myUN";
String PASSWORD = "myPW";
String HOST     = "https://zzzzzzz.zzzzz.zz.zz:9443";

// CookieSpecs.STANDARD is the RFC 6265 compliant policy
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig
                              .custom()
                              .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
                              .build();

// automatically follow redirects
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients
                            .custom()
                            .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
                            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                            .build();
HttpPost postIT                  = new HttpPost(HOST + "/qm/authenticated/identity");
List<NameValuePair> urlParams    = new ArrayList<>();

urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", USER));
urlParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", PASSWORD));
postIT.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParams));

HttpResponse mmmCookie = client.execute(postIT);
// ... we have our cookie!
```

For **postIT** the value is:

> POST https://zzzzz.zzz.zzzz.zzzz:9443/qm/authenticated/identity HTTP/1.1

However, it has an error of:

> error: null

Not sure why the error is null since **postIT** has data? So not only am I not able to run the modified code I did, I'm still wondering how I go about calling a **GET** command using the **cookie** even if the code above worked.

So, in a nutshell:

- Fix httpPost error.
- How to send cookie on other GET methods.

Help would be great!

**update for VGR:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath();
    PermissiveTrustManager blah = new PermissiveTrustManager();

    blah.readMembers("https://zzzzzz.zzzz.zz.zzz:9443", "zzzzzz", "zzzzzzz", currentRelativePath);
}
```

The error is on this line:

```
check(tm -> tm.checkServerTrusted(certChain, authType, socket), socket);
```

certChain, authType and socket all have data in them.

Comment: Where did `error: null` come from?  How did you print or view it?

Comment: @VGR The error came from HttpResponse mmmCookie = client.execute(postIT);

Comment: Are you saying that calling client.execute(postIT) caused `error: null` to appear on the screen somewhere?

Comment: @VGR Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Anyone else able to help me out on this?

Comment: It seems unusual for an HTTP library to print something, especially something so lacking in context.  Are you sure you don’t have any printing or logging statements which are causing that text to appear?

Comment: Yes I am very sure @VGR

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  Starting with Java 11, the [java.net.http](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html) package is available, which may give you better results.

Comment: The JRESE version is 1.8 and java version is 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don’t know what’s causing your cryptic error, I would suggest abandoning the third party library, and using the java.net package:

```
public void readMembers(String schemeAndAuthority,
                        String username,
                        String password,
                        Path membersFileToWrite)
throws IOException {

    URI baseURI = URI.create(schemeAndAuthority);

    CookieHandler oldCookieHandler = CookieHandler.getDefault();
    boolean oldFollowRedirects = HttpURLConnection.getFollowRedirects();

    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);

    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection;

        URI authURI = baseURI.resolve("/qm/authenticated/identity");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) authURI.toURL().openConnection();
        connection.getResponseCode();

        URI securityURI = baseURI.resolve(
            "/qm/authenticated/j_security_check");
        String postData = 
            "j_username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" +
            "j_password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)
            securityURI.toURL().openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        try (OutputStream postBody = connection.getOutputStream()) {
            postBody.write(postData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
        connection.getResponseCode();

        URI catalogURI = baseURI.resolve(
            "/qm/process/project-areas/_zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz/members");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)
            catalogURI.toURL().openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
        try (InputStream responseBody = connection.getInputStream()) {
            Files.copy(responseBody, membersFileToWrite);
        }
    } finally {
        CookieHandler.setDefault(oldCookieHandler);
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(oldFollowRedirects);
    }
}
```

However, the above code does not provide the equivalent of curl’s `-k` option.  For that, we have to create a custom [SSLContext](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html), initialized with a [TrustManager](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/TrustManager.html) that allows all certificates:

```
static class PermissiveTrustManager
extends X509ExtendedTrustManager {
    private final X509ExtendedTrustManager[] realTrustManagers;

    private interface Checker {
        void checkWith(X509ExtendedTrustManager realTrustManager)
        throws CertificateException;
    }

    PermissiveTrustManager() {
        TrustManagerFactory factory;
        try {
            factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            factory.init((KeyStore) null);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            // We should not be able to get here.
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        TrustManager[] allTrustManagers = factory.getTrustManagers();
        realTrustManagers = Arrays.stream(allTrustManagers)
            .filter(tm -> tm instanceof X509ExtendedTrustManager)
            .map(tm -> (X509ExtendedTrustManager) tm)
            .toArray(X509ExtendedTrustManager[]::new);

    }

    private void check(Checker checker) {
        try {
            for (X509ExtendedTrustManager realTrustManager : realTrustManagers) {
                checker.checkWith(realTrustManager);
            }
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            System.err.println("Ignoring invalid certificate");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void check(Checker checker,
                       Socket socket) {
        try {
            for (X509ExtendedTrustManager realTrustManager : realTrustManagers) {
                checker.checkWith(realTrustManager);
            }
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            System.err.println("Ignoring invalid certificate for " + 
                socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certChain,
                                   String authType,
                                   Socket socket) {
        check(tm -> tm.checkClientTrusted(certChain, authType, socket), socket);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certChain,
                                   String authType,
                                   SSLEngine engine) {
        check(tm -> tm.checkClientTrusted(certChain, authType, engine));
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certChain,
                                   String authType,
                                   Socket socket) {
        check(tm -> tm.checkServerTrusted(certChain, authType, socket), socket);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certChain,
                                   String authType,
                                   SSLEngine engine) {
        check(tm -> tm.checkServerTrusted(certChain, authType, engine));
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certChain,
                                   String authType) {
        check(tm -> tm.checkClientTrusted(certChain, authType));
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certChain,
                                   String authType) {
        check(tm -> tm.checkServerTrusted(certChain, authType));
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
}

private static SSLContext createPermissiveSSLContext()
throws IOException {

    TrustManager[] trustManagers = { new PermissiveTrustManager() };

    try {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, trustManagers, null);
        return context;
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}

public void readMembers(String schemeAndAuthority,
                        String username,
                        String password,
                        Path membersFileToWrite)
throws IOException {

    URI baseURI = URI.create(schemeAndAuthority);

    CookieHandler oldCookieHandler = CookieHandler.getDefault();
    boolean oldFollowRedirects = HttpURLConnection.getFollowRedirects();
    SSLContext oldSSLContext = null;
    try {
        oldSSLContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
    SSLContext.setDefault(createPermissiveSSLContext());

    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection;

        URI authURI = baseURI.resolve("/qm/authenticated/identity");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) authURI.toURL().openConnection();
        connection.getResponseCode();

        URI securityURI = baseURI.resolve(
            "/qm/authenticated/j_security_check");
        String postData = 
            "j_username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" +
            "j_password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)
            securityURI.toURL().openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        try (OutputStream postBody = connection.getOutputStream()) {
            postBody.write(postData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
        connection.getResponseCode();

        URI catalogURI = baseURI.resolve(
            "/qm/process/project-areas/_zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz/members");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)
            catalogURI.toURL().openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
        try (InputStream responseBody = connection.getInputStream()) {
            Files.copy(responseBody, membersFileToWrite);
        }
    } finally {
        CookieHandler.setDefault(oldCookieHandler);
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(oldFollowRedirects);
        if (oldSSLContext != null) {
            SSLContext.setDefault(oldSSLContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, I have no way to test this.

You could call the method like this:

```
new CatalogRetriever().readMembers(
    "https://zzzzzzz.zzzzz.zz.zz:9443", "myUN", "myPW",
    Paths.get("members"));
```

As described in [the URI docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html), the scheme is the `http:` or `https:` part.  The authority is `//` followed by a hostname/port (and optional user/password, depending on the protocol).

Comment: What should **schemeAndAuthority** be? And I am guessing that **readMembers** is what I need to be calling in the main function?

Comment: @StealthRT Updated answer with example method call.

Comment: I'm getting the error **PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

Comment: Try removing all the `e.printStackTrace();` lines.  The PermissiveTrustManager class deliberately swallows certificate exceptions.  Also `Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath()` will not work;  you need to pass the Path of a file (which doesn’t need to exist), not a directory.

Comment: Okay i did that and its now saying **cannot write to a URLConnection if doOutput=false - call setDoOutput(true)** The line is this: **try (OutputStream postBody = connection.getOutputStream()) {**

Comment: Oops, my mistake.  Answer updated.  `connection.setDoOutput(true);` is needed before the `try (OutputStream postBody` statement.

Comment: Alright that seems to have fix that. Can you give me an example of the **Also Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath() will not work; you need to pass the Path of a file (which doesn’t need to exist), not a directory**?

Comment: The example method call at the end of my answer contains such an example.

Comment: Yep. Tested it a few times and it all seems to work. I would have never thought of doing all of that so thank you VGR!